Connect multiple databases with same structure from spring boot microservices
I am working with Spring Boot Microservice project, in this I need to connect to multiple database with same structure based on countries.
What I have done :

I have created three configurations in application.properties file.

Created three configuration classes to connect with three databases.
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
entityManagerFactoryRef = "abbPhEntityManagerFactory", basePackages = {
"com.abb.admin.outletph" }
)
public class AbbDbPhConfig {
 @Bean(name = "abbphdatasource")
 @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.abb.ph.datasource")
 public DataSource dataSource() {
     return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
 }

 @Bean(name = "abbPhEntityManagerFactory")
 public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
         @Qualifier("abbphdatasource") DataSource dataSource) {
     Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
     properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none");
     properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect");
     return builder.dataSource(dataSource).properties(properties).packages("com.abb.admin.outletph")
             .persistenceUnit("ABBOutletPhMaster").build();
 }

 @Bean(name = "abbPhTransactionManager")
 public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
         @Qualifier("abbPhEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
     return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
 }

}

Created Entities and Repositories to access the data.


To connect with multiple databases I need to make many changes in already existing code, though I know that the structure like : table name, table columns will be same in all databases.
Can't I use same entities and repositories as DB structure is same, just I need to GET/PUT data in different structure without lots of code changes of different entity and repo classes?
If Yes then how can I achieve this?

Multi-tenancy might be what you're looking for. Have a look here. This way, you can call which database to call during runtime and they will use the same entities and repositories you configured for your multi-tenant datasource
